# Deploy SIP Communicator (Jitsi) on another existing osgi framework, and can control it, by osgi console

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, jitsi

I'm using SIP Communicator (Jitsi). It starts felix then deploy its bundle, when I close sipCom, it uninstalls all bundle then close felix framework too. Now I deployed my bundle, but I want after closing sip_communicator, felix should in work and my bundle should not stop.
for this below one idea but I don't know how to implement:

Start fresh felix osgi, deploy my bundle, then deploy SIP_Communicator's bundle.
for close sipcom, stop SIP_Communicator's bundle.

Problem: I don't know which bundle need to be deployed on felix that can control SIP Communicator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to deploy all the given bundle in sip communicator package in another osgi framework like `knopflerfish / equinox`. And follow the start level as given in build.xml of sip communicator package.
this should work.